# Change json file with python to categorize the objects

Tags: python, json

I want to make a json file with results taken from my database so, i am taking the results from database and i am making the json :

```
 for result in data_list:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(column_names, result)))
json_out = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)
```

My json out is something like :

```
[{"name" : "Jhon", "surname" : "smith"} , {"name" : "george", "surname" : "black"}]
```

But i want to be like

```
["employees":{{"name" : "Jhon", "surname" : "smith"} , {"name" :"george","surname" : "black"}}]
```

How is tha possible??

Comment: no, because the expected output is invalid

Comment: Your output isn’t valid syntax in Python or JSON, so no. You *could* have an object (dictionary) with the key employees and the value an array (list) of people, you just need to put the existing list into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Since your expected output is not valid JSON (or makes sense in the first place), you should have a Python dictionary with an element called `employees` and assign `json_data` to it.

Then, you call `json_dumps()` on that dictionary:

```
for result in data_list:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(column_names, result)))

final_json = {} # this is the Python dict I was talking about
final_json['employees'] = json_data
json_out = json.dumps(final_json, indent=4)
```

Result:

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "surname": "so",
            "name": "gi"
        },
        {
            "surname": "lo",
            "name": "lo"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a good representation of the data you want, because you're representing a static list of employees, which must be represented as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tablib

```
import tablib

headers = ["name", "surname"]
data = [
    ("jhon", "smit"),
    ("george", "black")
]
data = tablib.Dataset(*data, headers=headers)
data.json
```

### Result:

```
[{"name": "jhon", "surname": "smit"}, {"name": "george", "surname": "black"}]
```